# VS 2013 Express - VB Update Database

Tags: database, express

I've looked all over and can't find an answer to my question. I'm trying to do the simplest database I can. I want to be able to add/edit/delete items and have it save them to the database, so they're in there the next time I open it.

I'm currently using VS 2013 Express and have the 2012 express still installed.  was going through the MSDN tutorials and even tried the Northwind Database, but it said I had to upgrade it, but that it wouldn't allow me to. So now I'm stuck.

Currently, I've created a database, then a new project. I connected the new project to the database and drag-n-dropped one of the tables onto the form in gridview. In the interest of saving space, I won't go into a lot of detail. I basically followed the msdn tutorial on creating two tables called Customers and Orders, with a few variables and 3 entries a piece. There is a primary key in customers and a foreign key in orders.

I used the code MSDN provided, that was similar to what was already in the save buttons auto-generated code, except in a try/catch code. What I have so far is:

`Private Sub CustomersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CustomersBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        ' Me.Validate()
        ' Me.CustomersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        'Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.SampleDatabaseDataSet)

```
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.CustomersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Update(Me.SampleDatabaseDataSet.Customers)
        MsgBox("Update successful")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Update failed")
    End Try

End Sub`
```

I apologize for the code not all being in the block, I couldn't get it to work properly. So, from what I can determine, it looks like this code updates the dataset and not the database. Is that true? If so, how do I update the database? When I run the program and add a row, I can click save and it returns a message box, saying it ran successfully. However, I can't rerun the program and have it display, much less shut the VS Express down and bring it back up to have it show the changes. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've found the answer to this question. It appears that what's happening is that there are two versions of the database. One version is stored in the root of the project folder, the other is stored in the bin/debug folder.

Apparently, for whatever reason, when you run your program to test your code it pulls from the root database. Any changes you make and save are copied to the one in bin/debug. I assume this is so that you can have stock information in your database and not have it altered by code that may or may not work the way you want. I understand that, but I think there is just as much reason to want it to save changes. I wish there were an option to make it that way and if anyone knows how, please share that.

I've spent a couple of years playing with databases, on and off, thinking I was doing something wrong, when in reality it's just the way VS was handling it. You can do one of two things to test if this is your issue. One is that you can go into the bin/debug and copy the .mdf and the .ldf, and paste them into the root folder, overwriting the two there. I'm not sure what the .ldf does, but it wouldn't run without it. Then when you go to runtime, your changes will be reflected. Another option is build your project and run the .exe in your bin/debug folder. It will run the program and any changes you make will stick, but again, only in the bin/debug version. I assume that a published project will save to the root directory.

I found the article that led to this breakthrough here: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2012/05/dealing-with-local-databases-or-why-your-updates-dont-stick.aspx